# customize scroll indicator of UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, vertical-scrolling

I wanted to customize scroll indicator of `UIWebView` where i am loading local PDF file in `UIWebView`. I need the requirement as in image shown here. Can any one share your ideas to get this.

[image: scroll indicator of <code>UIWebView</code>]

Answer (score 2):

In WebView there is scrollview that we can customise according to requirement.

```
UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:webView];

UIScrollView *scrollView;
scrollView =  webView.scrollView;
scrollView.delegate = self;
```

And there is UIScrollView Delegate
that help you in custmoise ScrollView

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1
{
//get refrence of vertical indicator
UIImageView *verticalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-1)]);
//set color to vertical indicator
[verticalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];


//get refrence of horizontal indicator
UIImageView *horizontalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-2)]);
//set color to horizontal indicator
[horizontalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

}

Comment: how can i set the required width to this indicator @kavitha

Comment: we can not change the width of that indicator but if you want to put image on place of indicator then take the image size accordingly